# paper-dropdown-menu - how to collapse dropdown menu when repeat a selection

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

When you repeat the same selection item, already selected, the dropdown menu remains open. I would like to collapse the menu as it occurs when you select a different item. You can check this behavior in the [demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-dropdown-menu). How can I modify the element to collapse the menu in any case?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper-dropdown-menu has an 'opened' property. You can listen on click of the dropdown content and if `opened` is true, set it to `false`.